# Can't iterate from BlogPost object in my template (Django)

Tags: python, django, mezzanine

I can't iterate through BlogPost object in my templates. Nothing is showing up for some reason. I probably forgot something. In the shell I can obtain the objects without any problem. So something is wrong, and I can't figure out what.

**views.py:**

```
def latest_posts(request):
    latest_posts = BlogPost.objects.all().filter(site_id=1)[:50]
    render(request, (settings.PROJECT_ROOT + "/main/templates/includes/latest_posts.html"), {"latest_posts": latest_posts})
```

**latest_posts.html:**

```
{% load pages_tags mezzanine_tags i18n accounts_tags %}

<div class="panel panel-default" >
    <div class="panel-heading">
      <h3 class="panel-title">{% trans "Latest Posts" %}</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="panel-body" style="padding:0;border:0px;">


      {% for lp in latest_posts %}
      <ul class="list-group-latest-posts">
        <li class="list-group-item-latest-posts">
          <img class="media-object left" src="#" width="40" height="40" alt="#">
          <p>{{ lp.title }}<br><span class="latest-post-name">user_name</span><span class="latest-post-divider"> - </span><span class="latest-post-time">6 Hours Ago</span></p>
        </li>
        </ul>
      {% endfor %}
      </div>
</div>
```

**This is my structure. In base.html:**

```
{% if '/' in request.path %}
{% else %}
  {% include "includes/sidebar.html" %}
{% endif %}
```

**sidebar.html:**

```
<div class="col-md-4 right">
      {% include 'includes/latest_posts.html' %}
</div>
```

**In my urls.py:**

```
url("^$", direct_to_template, {"template": "index.html"}, name="home"),
```

Comment: Just out of curiosity, can you output `{{ latest_posts.count }}` and `{{ latest_posts }}`

Comment: @Sayse: No output I'm afraid.

Comment: Ok, then it sounds like caching. Can you try reloading the page with `ctrl` + `shift` + `r`

Comment: @Sayse: Tried that. Nothing worked. But is it any different that I am on the index page (base.html) and have included the latest_post inside it? Could that be the cause of this?

Comment: Potentially, `include` inherits the `context_data` of the parent, but if you're accessing the page from a different view then obviously it will never call this view, and won't take its context either

Comment: it would help if you could show the view and templates for the url you're viewing

Comment: @Sayse is correct... you can not import the latest_posts.html template from the base.html, unless you have latest_posts in the view that called the base.html page. Typically you have latest_posts.html {% extends 'base.html' %}

Comment: @Sayse: I added more information regarding this in my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're page is loaded from a different view called `direct_to_template` that has nothing to do with the `latest_posts` view so it will never find its context data.

So now 1 of two things needs to happen, either you just consume the code from `latest_posts` re: the context data into that other view and include it in that context. Or you make a url to point to that page

```
from views import latest_posts
url("^latest_posts$", latest_posts, name="latest_posts"),
```

Now this will get you the posts showing from the url `/latest_posts`, but it probably doesn't look very pretty, it could be an option to have the `latest_posts` view still load the base.html template which will make it look more like you expect, although a browse through the documentation on [template inheritance](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/templates/#templates) may help more

Comment: Note: you'll start getting errors when calling this view now if you didn't change that view to return the render as per my previous answer

Comment: Holy moly. I just created a new home view and pointed my url to that and VOILA! It displays my latest posts so perfectly. Thank you @Sayse so much for guide me through this. Really awesome!

Comment: @InteL - No worries, enjoy! I'd strongly suggest you look into the `extends` template tag and the other link in my answer

Comment: I will definitely do that. :)